# Converting a DSE Search node to a DSE Spark node

Tags: solr, apache-spark, datastax

I saw from the [FAQ](http://www.datastax.com/resources/faq#dse-24) that a DSE node can be reprovisioned from RT mode to Hadoop mode. Is something similar supported with DSE Search and DSE Spark? I have an existing 6-node DSE Search cluster. I want to test DSE Spark but I have very limited time left for development so if possible, I'd like to skip the bootstrap process by simply restarting my cluster as an Analytics DC instead of adding new nodes in a separate DC.

UPDATE:

I tried to find an answer on my own. These are the closest that I found:

http://www.datastax.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/WP-DataStax-WhatsNewDSE2.pdf
http://www.datastax.com/doc-source/pdf/dse20.pdf

These documents are for a very old release of DSE. Both documents say that only RT and Analytics node can be re-provisioned. The second document even explicitly says that a Solr node cannot be re-provisioned. Unfortunately, there is no mention about re-provisioning in more recent documentations. 
Can anybody confirm whether this is still true with DSE 4.5.1? (preferably with a link to a reference)

I also saw this [forum thread](http://www.datastax.com/support-forums/topic/documentation-on-elastic-workload-re-provisioning-missing-for-dse-31) which explains why the section about re-provisioning was removed in recent documentations. However, in my case, I plan to re-provision all of my Search nodes as Analytics node (in contrast to re-provisioning only a subset), and the re-provisioning would only be temporary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that. Just start it using 'dse Cassandra -k'

Comment: Do you have a source to back this up? I'm about to try this in a semi-production cluster. I just want to be sure that I can revert to Solr after my test. Take note that my column families have special secondary indexes of type "com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.Cql3SolrSecondaryIndex". I'm not sure if this would cause any issue in Spark

Comment: I tested this today and I can confirm that a Solr DC can indeed be re-provisioned as an Analytics DC. (note: I only tested DC-wide re-provisioning)